# Optimizar una consulta a la base de datos en php

Tags: php, mysql

otra vez acá con una duda de novato.

Resulta que tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
public function setSpam(){
    global $tsCore, $tsUser, $tsActividad;
    //
    $postid = $_POST['postid'];
    // TIENE SEGUIDORES?
    $query = db_exec(array(__FILE__, __LINE__), 'query', 'SELECT follow_id FROM u_follows WHERE f_id = \''.$tsUser->uid.'\'  AND f_type = \'1\' LIMIT 1');
    $seguidores = db_exec('num_rows', $query);
    // YA LO HA RECOMENDADO?
    $query = db_exec(array(__FILE__, __LINE__), 'query', 'SELECT follow_id FROM u_follows WHERE f_id = \''.(int)$postid.'\' AND f_user = \''.$tsUser->uid.'\' AND f_type = \'3\' LIMIT 1');
    $recomendado = db_exec('num_rows', $query);

    if($seguidores < 1) return '0-Debes tener al menos un seguidor';
    if($recomendado > 0) return '0-No puedes recomendar el mismo post m&aacute;s de una vez.'; 
    //
    $query = db_exec(array(__FILE__, __LINE__), 'query', 'SELECT post_user FROM p_posts WHERE post_id = \''.(int)$postid.'\' LIMIT 1');
    $data = db_exec('fetch_assoc', $query);

    //
    if($tsUser->uid != $data['post_user']){
        // GUARDAMOS EN FOLLOWS PUES ES LA RECOMENDACION PARA SU SEGUIDORES! xD
        db_exec(array(__FILE__, __LINE__), 'query', 'INSERT INTO u_follows (f_id, f_user, f_type, f_date) VALUES (\''.(int)$postid.'\', \''.$tsUser->uid.'\', \'3\', \''.time().'\') ');
        // NOTIFICAR
        if($this->setFollowNotificacion(6, 1, $tsUser->uid, $postid)) {
            $tsActividad->setActividad(4, $postid);
            return '1-La recomendaci&oacute;n fue enviada.';
        }
    } else return '0-No puedes recomendar tus posts.';
}
```

Lo que hace básicamente es recomendar un artículo (post) de la siguiente manera. Si yo entro a un artículo y lo quiero compartir puedo hacerlo sin problema si tengo 1 o 2 seguidores pero el problema es que si tengo unos 1000 entonces la función está durante un par de minutos (lo cual es demasiado) y además realentiza mucho mi servidor.

Estaba pensando en que quizá podría modificarla para que solo la comparta con seguidores que iniciaron sesión hace 2 días mínimo pero no tengo idea cómo y tampoco se si esa sería la solución correcta.

Comment: Armar de esta forma el timeline de cada usuario no va a ser óptimo, mucho menos si hay varios usuarios leyendo y escribiendo (cargando posts y registrando recomendaciones). Posiblemente es necesario que ese registro de recomendaciones se haga por lotes y asíncrono.

Comment: La optimización depende mucho más de cómo esté estructurado tu modelo, tu base de datos, si tiene índices, llaves primarias, etc. Además, trata de hacer menos procesos con php y usar más procedimientos almacenados, eso optimiza más tu aplicativo teniendo un mejor control de los procesos dentro de.